# Match H[0-9][0-9] but not match any letter except letter H

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to perform a regex match in SQL Server.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU1) (KB4527376) - 15.0.4003.23 (X64)   Dec  6 2019 14:53:33   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0 (Ootpa))

to query that looks as follows:
`SELECT * FROM *table* WHERE [Item] LIKE '[H][0-9][0-9]%'`

`[H][0-9][0-9]%` will match start with letter `H` only and [0-9] can matches any number from 0-9.I put twice mean will get two  number after `H`,  `%` will match Any string, because I want to get item like `H03.1`.

Here is my datatable:

| id | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | H23 |
| 2 | H03.1 |
| 3 | H030BZZ |
| 4 | H03YYZZ |
| 5 | H2261ZZ |
| 6 | H51Q1ZZ |

I want to only match H[0-9][0-9] but not match any letter except letter `H`.
For example: I want to get H23 and H03.1 but not get  H030BZZ, H03YYZZ, H2261ZZ, H51Q1ZZ.

I have tried the code like:

```
WHERE [Item]  NOT LIKE '[H][0-9]{0,3}[A-Z]{0,3}
```

but still can't achieve my goal. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Would `H46H` be a match?

Comment: What about `H2356#4`? Please explain your matching criteria in more detail with regards to characters which can follow the `H[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: @Nick, I re-edit my question.

Comment: It's still not clear whether `H46H` would be allowed?

Comment: H46H not match.

Comment: FYI the version of SSMS is irrelevant, as its just a client UI, you want the version of SQL Server which you get by `select @@version`

Comment: FYI, SQL Server does *not* support Regex, only basic pattern matching. If you need Regex support you'd need to look into a different using external tools or CLR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this query to check first if the `Item` starts with `H[0-9][0-9]` and then check that it doesn't include a letter after the first 3 characters:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE [Item] LIKE '[H][0-9][0-9]%'
  AND [Item] NOT LIKE '___%[A-Z]%'
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
id  Item
1   H23
2   H03.1
```

Demo on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KsXoCsXH)

Comment: @Ollie I've just updated the answer to not allow any letters after the first three characters (so `H64H` will not match either)